# How to implement OAuth in Bitrix for third party Applications?

Tags: java, php, oauth, bitrix

I am currently using [Bitrix24](https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/) for HR management and task management.

Since it provides an option to integrate third party applications with it, I am stuck in how to implement `OAuth` for my application with Bitrix.

I went through documentation provided by Bitrix24 but it uses php code.

Is there any sample JAVA code available for `OAuth` implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately havent seen any examples on other that PHP languages, but
if you are already experienced with Java it should not be a problem.
In case you are working with bitrix24 cloud edition - you need to

1) create application for marketplace using you partner account and obtain **secret key** and **application id**

2) send this **secret key** and **application id** from your application written on any language and receive

3) receive **request token** and **refresh_token** and use them to access rest api provided by Bitrix24 https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/

more details on what kind of request you need to do: https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/oauth/examles.php

hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API like this for JAVA

I am adding LEADS from the API, and updating the same LEAD

to add the LEAD:-
Method: POST

URL:-
https://.bitrix24.com/rest/crm.lead.add

Parameters:-
{"fields[TITLE]":"LEAD_TITLE","auth":"AUTH_TOKEN"}

- It will add the new LEAD in you Bitrix Dashboard.